# How to center this form on large screen?

Tags: html, css, position

I'm build a page with a form that I would like to center, however I couldn't achieve that ausing auto for padding or margin (Although I gave the form a fixed width) .

Here's my HTML structure:

```
<div class = "parent row">
    <div class = "child1 row">
        <form>
            <legend>
                Inputs goes here
            </legend>
            <legend>
                Inputs goes here 
            </legend>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class = "child2 row">
        <form>
            <legend>
                Inputs goes here
            </legend>
            <legend>
                Inputs goes here 
            </legend>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using skeleton grid system, And I have a parent `div` which represent a `row` and which has two children : Both have a form with `fieldset` .

I tried giving a fixed width to each one of them and using padding-auto and margin-auto and it didn't work .

Here the styling code (with SCSS) :

```
form{
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
}
legend,fieldset{
  border: 1px grey solid;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 0 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
  h4{
    background-color: $primary-blue-color;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom : 40px; 
  }
  input{
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

On small screens the parent div get centred, but on larger screens it doesn't . it's aligned in a standard way (from left) .

How can I make that div and all it children get centred on all type of screens ?

Comment: Please post the css snippet that is currently centering the row on smaller screens.

Comment: Do you want even vertical centered?

Comment: @DeepakBandi No, I want to center it vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You got to remove the width on legend/fieldset:</strike>

Add:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This includes the padding and border in the width of every element. You could always select only the form and it's elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
}

legend,
fieldset {
  border: 1px grey solid;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 0 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
  
  h4 {
    background-color: $primary-blue-color;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  
  input {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent row">
  <div class="child1 row">
    <form>
      <legend>
        Inputs goes here
      </legend>
      <legend>
        Inputs goes here
      </legend>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="child2 row">
    <form>
      <legend>
        Inputs goes here
      </legend>
      <legend>
        Inputs goes here
      </legend>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: Remove these pieces of code for it to work:

[image: offending code]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just remove width

```
legend, fieldset {
   border: 1px grey solid;
   max-width: 400px;
   padding: 0 25%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   /* width: 350px; */
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want it to be vertically centered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

        <style>
        .parent{
            height: 100vh;// give your height here
        }
        .child-wrapper{
            position          : relative;
            top               : 50%;
            -webkit-transform : translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform     : translateY(-50%);
            transform         : translateY(-50%);
            display           : table;
            margin            : 0 auto;
        }
        form{
            max-width: 400px;
            min-width: 250px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 350px;
        }
        legend,fieldset{
            border: 1px grey solid;
            max-width: 400px;
            padding: 0 25%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            /*width: 350px;*/
        }
        h4{
            background-color: $primary-blue-color;
            color: white;
            margin-bottom : 40px;
        }
        input{
            margin: 5px;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "parent row">
            <div class="child-wrapper">
                <div class = "child1 row">
                    <form>
                        <legend>
                            Inputs goes here
                        </legend>
                        <legend>
                            Inputs goes here
                        </legend>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class = "child2 row">
                    <form>
                        <legend>
                            Inputs goes here
                        </legend>
                        <legend>
                            Inputs goes here
                        </legend>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```